# Excel Sheet display in android

Tags: android, excel, spreadsheet

I want to display an excel sheet in my android application. I have googled and yet cannot find a starting tip to render an excel file using android components. If anybody knows any thing please give me some valuable hint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or Java Excel [API.](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I tried both Apache Poi and Java Excel Api. Both can be used to read from and write to an excel file. ok. But I want to display the data from excel in a grid type view using table layout. can you help me in that

Answer (score 0):

In android jxl.jar is use for create excel sheet. and it is available at [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjxljar.htm)

and you can create excel sheet by using following code.
  `File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`
`File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);`
`FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);`
`writer.append("NAME");`

Answer (score -1):

Try [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html).