# Report viewer in Android

Tags: android

Is there any report viewer tool or api in android for generating reports of any form.
I want to create sales report, purchase report in my android phone. So i am looking an api or framework which makes my work easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Excel For creating Reports like Sales and Purchase.

Please look at [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11200875/1405983) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919531/how-to-open-excel-sheet-in-android/11190527#11190527) for create excelsheet reports in android.

Also refer [Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html).